# How do i add a reaction to a certain person's message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently in the middle of making a bot for one of my friend's server. The main aim of the bot is to annoy a certain discord user in the chat by always reacting to their message with a regular emoji.

*I haven't used discord.py in a long while, so please don't be too critical, cheers.*

here's what i have already:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # event that happens per any message.
    print(message.author.id)
    if message.author.id == <user id>:
        await message.add_reaction("<emoji>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks absolutely fine.

Just make sure that when you're adding a reaction, make sure that it's one of the following:

- Unicode - `\u2705`
- The emoji itself - ✅ (if your IDE supports it)
- (For custom emojis) The name and ID - `<:emoji_name:112233445566778899>`

You can use [this website](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_emoticons.html) to find the unicode/string representation for emojis and paste them in.
For custom emojis, you can type `\:emoji_name:` into discord and send the message, and you'll receive it in the format you need.

For example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == 112233445566778899:
        await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) - Specifically:
  [image]
- [`Client.get_emoji()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_emoji) - An alternative for getting custom emoji objects.

Comment: No worries! If it helped, don't forget to [accept the answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as it might help others with the same issue. Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)